# $\{1/n\}$ doesn't converge in $(0, \infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Given the metric space $(0, \infty)$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$, the sequence $\{1/n\}$ does not converge. I'm trying to prove this from the definition, namely that given $M \in (0,\infty)$, we have
$$ 
\exists \epsilon > 0, \; \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \; \exists n \geq N, \; |p_n - M| \geq \epsilon.
$$
Thus far my attempts have not worked, but here is the best I was able to do, explaining my thought process throughout.

> As a baseline, I'm going to take $\epsilon = \frac{M}{2}$. Take $N$ arbitrary and $n \geq N$ (conditions to be specified after) and consider
> $$ 
> |p_n - M| = \left \lvert \frac{1}{n} - M \right \rvert.
> $$
> I need to do something with the sign here. If I require $\frac{1}{n} - M \geq 0$, then $M \leq \frac{1}{n}$, but $M$ can be arbitrarily large, so I can't impose this restriction, so I need to instead take $\frac{1}{n} - M \leq 0$, so $M \geq \frac{1}{n}$. So the restriction is $n \geq \frac{1}{M}$.
> $$ 
> |p_n - M| = \left \lvert \frac{1}{n} - M \right \rvert = - \left(\frac{1}{n} - M\right) = M - \frac{1}{n}.
> $$
> I need to get rid of $n$ somehow. Since $\frac{1}{n} \leq M$, we have $- \frac{1}{n} \geq - M$, so $M - \frac{1}{n} \geq 0$, so that doesn't help. I want to in some way get $M - \frac{1}{n} \geq \frac{M}{2}$. Rearranging, I get $\frac{M}{2} \geq \frac{1}{n}$. So $n \geq \frac{2}{M} \geq \frac{1}{M}$, so the above restriction still holds.

How does this look?

Comment: The sequence converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. By uniqueness of limits it can't converge in $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Your title mentions the space $(0,\infty)$, but in the first sentence you write $[0,\infty)$. Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $(0, \infty)$. This sequence would converge if I included $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something along these lines:

Suppose $(x_n)$ converges to some $x \in (0,\infty)$. Then there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$ $\frac{1}{n}= x_n < \frac{x}{2}$. Contradiction!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not seeing where the contradiction is?

Comment: If $x_n < x/2$ for all $n$ big enough, then at the limit you get $x\leq x/2$ which is a contradiction for $x\in (0,+\infty)$.